# When is a Java object still reachable?

Tags: java

It is about the quiz from java magazine https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/java-quiz-object-reachability. Here is the code snippet:

```
01: var rl = new ArrayList<Repairable>();
02: var car = new Car();
03: var clutch = car.getClutch();
04: var engine = (Repairable) null;
05: rl.add(car);
06: rl.add(clutch);
07: car = null;
08: clutch = null;
09: rl.add(engine);
10: rl.set(2, engine);
11: rl.remove(0);
12: rl.remove(1);
```

I am quite irritated by this quiz. I am particularly surprised by the statement "Line 12 removes the item at index 1, which is the null. The list, therefore, contains nothing except the clutch." At this point in time is clutch also zero(line 08) and accordingly that is not right.

Comment: have you tried running this code through a debugger?

Comment: setting clutch to null at line 08 does not change the reference of clutch added to list in line 06 to null. That's why clutch still exists in list and so does car because it's the enclosing class.

Comment: "and so does car because it's the enclosing class" The `Car` instance became unreachable at line `11` as the local variable `car` is already null, and now it is no longer in the list.

Comment: @tgdavies Yes but as the enclosing class it is reachable *via* the `Clutch` inner class instance.

Comment: @KonradRudolph From the question there's no reason to think that Clutch is an inner class.

Comment: @tgdavies It is, if you follow the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am particularly surprised by the statement "Line 12 removes the item at index 1, which is the null. The list, therefore, contains nothing except the clutch."

I was too, until I remembered that `remove` *shifts the indices* in the `ArrayList`!

Here is what’s happening to `rl`:

1. Before line 11:

   | 0 | 1 | 2 |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | `car` | `clutch` | `null` |
2. After line 11 (`rl.remove(0);`):

   | 0 | 1 |
   | --- | --- |
   | `clutch` | `null` |
3. After line 12 (`rl.remove(1);`):

   | 0 |
   | --- |
   | `clutch` |

Consequently, the `Clutch` object created in the `Car` object constructor is still alive at the end of the code snippet, and so is its containing `Car` instance.